# Mobile Safari CKEDITOR cursor moves out of text area when typing

Tags: jquery, ios, css, ckeditor, mobile-safari

I've set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate the trouble that I'm running into.  You have to open the link on an iPad or the iPad simulator running iOS 6 or 7 with Mobile Safari.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtidy/j4xPh/1/

You should see CKEDITOR available in the lower-right and when you put the cursor in there and start typing you should see the cursor actually move to appear between HEADER and CONTENT.  Whatever you type still appears in the CKEDITOR.  If you scroll the screen so that you can see the contents of CKEDITOR and type then you'll see what you type until you hit the spacebar or start a new word at which point the cursor moves up and your view changes so you see the cursor between HEADER and CONTENT again.

Here's the structure of my page:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content">
      CONTENT
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea name="test-editor" id="test-editor" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is all of the JS that I have on my page:

```
CKEDITOR.replace("test-editor");
```

Does anyone know the cause?  If not, could you help me narrow down the cause?  If I run a demo like this where CKEDITOR is not in an iframe then it works great on the iPad but if my view is wrapped in an iframe (such as with jsfiddle) then I get this funny cursor behavior on the iPad.

Thank you.

Comment: We're now working on a bug which looks similar to yours - http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10714 which is caused by Safari's bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=128924. It seems that they may have the same cause, so the patch for #10714 may help for your bug too.

Comment: Or I was wrong... your bug seems to be caused by the same bug in Webkit, because in your case some offsets are also incorrectly computed by Webkit, but I'm afraid that hack for #10714 won't help. Make sure to report this bug on https://bugs.webkit.org - maybe one day it'll be fixed...

Comment: BTW, the work-around for this is to add the [divarea](http://ckeditor.com/addon/divarea) plugin to CKEDITOR.  I'd rather not have to do that but this does appear to be a limitation in Mobile Safari rather than an issue in the CKEDITOR implementation that can be worked-around without replacing the iframe.